# why ProtocolSocketFactory not present in httpclient5?

Tags: httpclient, opensaml

I am trying to upgrade httpclient to httpclient5 distribution. But openSAML refers to ProtocolSocketFactory which is not present in httpclient5 version.
I am using OpenSAML 2.6.6

Please let me know if anyone aware of this issue.